# Rss Reader giving Android Runtime Error

Tags: java, android, saxparser, rss-reader

I'm building a RSS/Atom feed reader which check different tag and takes in only the tags that we need.

However, when I execute the code, I'm having an Android RunTime Exception.

```
04-29 23:56:20.745: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgressDrawable mProgressDrawable = null, d = android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable@42347548needUpdate = false
04-29 23:56:20.745: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 32
04-29 23:56:20.745: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 0
04-29 23:56:20.745: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:20.745: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:20.755: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 0
04-29 23:56:20.755: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:20.755: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:20.865: D/libEGL(18432): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
04-29 23:56:20.875: D/libEGL(18432): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
04-29 23:56:20.885: D/libEGL(18432): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
04-29 23:56:20.885: I/Adreno-EGL(18432): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: LNXBUILD_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_3.2.4.04.03.00.173.012+PATCH[ES]_msm8226_JB_3.2.4__release_ENGG ()
04-29 23:56:20.885: I/Adreno-EGL(18432): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 20.00.01
04-29 23:56:20.885: I/Adreno-EGL(18432): Build Date: 02/27/14 Thu
04-29 23:56:20.885: I/Adreno-EGL(18432): Local Branch: 
04-29 23:56:20.885: I/Adreno-EGL(18432): Remote Branch: quic/jb_3.2.4
04-29 23:56:20.885: I/Adreno-EGL(18432): Local Patches: 7de55685a2714b78da20f2a126b0dd72b0d2c0c4 Merge "PROFILER: fix default enabled/disabled setting"
04-29 23:56:20.885: I/Adreno-EGL(18432):                  75d04ab84c7a68c72d92d59aae1827fcfef44b91 PROFILER: fix default enabled/disabled setting
04-29 23:56:20.885: I/Adreno-EGL(18432): Reconstruct Branch: LOCAL_PATCH[ES]
04-29 23:56:20.925: D/OpenGLRenderer(18432): Enabling debug mode 0
04-29 23:56:20.925: D/ProgressBar(18432): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
04-29 23:56:20.925: D/ProgressBar(18432): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
04-29 23:56:20.925: D/ProgressBar(18432): updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
04-29 23:56:20.925: D/ProgressBar(18432): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 32
04-29 23:56:20.925: D/ProgressBar(18432): updateDrawableBounds: mProgressDrawable.setBounds()
04-29 23:56:21.885: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 1
04-29 23:56:21.885: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 1, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:21.885: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:21.895: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 2
04-29 23:56:21.895: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 2, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:21.895: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 1mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:21.895: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 3
04-29 23:56:21.895: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 3, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:21.895: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 2mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:21.905: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 4
04-29 23:56:21.905: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 4, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:21.905: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 3mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:21.945: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 5
04-29 23:56:21.945: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 5, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:21.945: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 4mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:21.955: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 6
04-29 23:56:21.955: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 6, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:21.955: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 5mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:21.955: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 7
04-29 23:56:21.955: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 7, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:21.955: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 6mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:21.965: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 8
04-29 23:56:21.965: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 8, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:21.965: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 7mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:21.975: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 9
04-29 23:56:21.975: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 9, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:21.975: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 8mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:21.985: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 10
04-29 23:56:21.985: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 10, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:21.985: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 9mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:21.985: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 11
04-29 23:56:21.985: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 11, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:21.985: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 10mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:21.995: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 12
04-29 23:56:21.995: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 12, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:21.995: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 11mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.015: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 13
04-29 23:56:22.015: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 13, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.015: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 12mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.015: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 14
04-29 23:56:22.015: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 14, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.015: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 13mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.025: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 15
04-29 23:56:22.025: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 15, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.025: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 14mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.035: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 16
04-29 23:56:22.035: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 16, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.035: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 15mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.045: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 17
04-29 23:56:22.045: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 17, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.045: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 16mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.045: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 18
04-29 23:56:22.045: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 18, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.045: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 17mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.065: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 19
04-29 23:56:22.065: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 19, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.065: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 18mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.075: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 20
04-29 23:56:22.075: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 20, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.075: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 19mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.075: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 21
04-29 23:56:22.075: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 21, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.075: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 20mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.085: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 22
04-29 23:56:22.085: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 22, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.085: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 21mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.095: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 23
04-29 23:56:22.095: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 23, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.095: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 22mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.095: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 24
04-29 23:56:22.095: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 24, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.095: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 23mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.105: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 25
04-29 23:56:22.105: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 25, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.105: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 24mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.115: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 100
04-29 23:56:22.115: D/ProgressBar(18432): setProgress = 100, fromUser = false
04-29 23:56:22.115: D/ProgressBar(18432): mProgress = 25mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
04-29 23:56:22.115: D/AndroidRuntime(18432): Shutting down VM
04-29 23:56:22.115: W/dalvikvm(18432): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41758898)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at com.itcuties.app.SplashActivity$GetRSSDataTask.onPostExecute(SplashActivity.java:81)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at com.itcuties.app.SplashActivity$GetRSSDataTask.onPostExecute(SplashActivity.java:1)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
04-29 23:56:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18432):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 23:57:07.065: I/Process(18432): Sending signal. PID: 18432 SIG: 9
```

Here's my java File which does that,

```
package com.itcuties.app.util.atom;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.itcuties.app.reader.data.RssAtomItem;
import com.itcuties.app.util.text.TextConverter;


public class RssAtomParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<RssAtomItem> rssItems;

    // Used to reference item while parsing
    private RssAtomItem currentItem;

    // Parsing title indicator
    private boolean parsingTitle;
    // Parsing contents indicator
    private boolean parsingContents;
    // Parsing published date indicator
    private boolean parsingPublishedDate;
    // A buffer for title contents
    private StringBuffer currentTitleSb;
    // A buffer for content tag contents
    private StringBuffer currentContentSb;
    // A buffer for publish date tag contents;
    private StringBuffer currentPubishDateSb;
    // Parsing published Author name
    private boolean parsingAuthorName;
    // A buffer for Author Name
    private StringBuffer currentAuthorSb;

    // This is a ProgressBar reference set by the SplashScreen
    // We use it to show the real progress while each item from
    // the feed is read.
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public RssAtomParseHandler() {
        rssItems = new ArrayList<RssAtomItem>();
    }

    public List<RssAtomItem> getItems() {
        return rssItems;
    }

    public void setProgressBar(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if ("entry".equals(qName)) {
            currentItem = new RssAtomItem();
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
            parsingTitle = true;
            currentTitleSb = new StringBuffer();
        } else if ("author".equals(qName)) {
            parsingAuthorName = true;
            currentAuthorSb = new StringBuffer();
        } else if ("content".equals(qName)) {
            parsingContents = true;
            currentContentSb = new StringBuffer();
        } else if ("published".equals(qName)) {
            parsingPublishedDate = true;
            currentPubishDateSb = new StringBuffer();
        } else if ("category".equals(qName)) {
            if (currentItem != null && currentItem.getCategory() == null) {
                currentItem.setCategory(attributes.getValue("term"));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if ("entry".equals(qName)) {
            rssItems.add(currentItem);
            currentItem = null;
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
            parsingTitle = false;

            // There is a title tag for a whole channel present.
            // It is being parsed before the entry tag is present,
            // so we need to check if item is not null
            if (currentItem != null)
                // We encode the title so that it can be read by the application
                // properly
                currentItem.setTitle(TextConverter.convertTitle(currentTitleSb
                        .toString()));

        } else if ("content".equals(qName)) {
            parsingContents = false;

            if (currentItem != null) {
                // When an item's content is being set we convert it a little
                // bit:
                // - All styles and JavaScript information are removed
                // - Content is URL encoded so that the WebView component can
                // display it correctly
                // - We remove two sections which are added by the ATOM feed,
                // the post info section
                // and the code download section (only github link is present in
                // the text)
                currentItem.setContent(TextConverter
                        .clearStylesAndJS(TextConverter.URLEncode(TextConverter
                                .removePostInfoSection(TextConverter
                                        .removeDownloadSection(currentContentSb
                                                .toString())))));

                // Update progressBar
                progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress() + 1);

            } else if ("author".equals(qName)) {
                parsingAuthorName = false;

                if (currentItem != null) {

                    currentItem.setAuthor(currentAuthorSb.toString());

                    // Update progressBar
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress() + 1);

                }

            } else if ("published".equals(qName)) {
                parsingPublishedDate = false;

                if (currentItem != null)
                    try {
                        // We convert the date from the WordPress format to
                        // DD-MM-YYYY format
                        currentItem.setPublishDate(TextConverter
                                .convertDate(currentPubishDateSb.toString()));
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        currentItem.setPublishDate("no date");
                        Log.e("ITCRssReader", "No publish date available");
                    }

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        // title, contents and date tags contents values are set here.
        // This method can be called multiple times for one tag, it depends
        // on how much text tag's contents has. Remember that SAX is a
        // stream parser so it parses feed stream sequentially.
        if (parsingTitle) {
            if (currentItem != null)
                currentTitleSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
        } else if (parsingAuthorName) {
            if (currentItem != null)
                currentAuthorSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));

            else if (parsingContents) {
                if (currentItem != null)
                    currentContentSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
            } else if (parsingPublishedDate) {
                if (currentItem != null)
                    currentPubishDateSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the Splash Activity that uses AsyncTask.

```
package com.itcuties.app;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.itcuties.app.reader.data.RssAtomItem;
import com.itcuties.app.reader.data.RssResults;
import com.itcuties.app.util.atom.RssAtomReader;

/**
 * Application splash screen. It also loads data.
 * 

 */
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Toast t;
    String done ="Done!";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setProgress(0); // No progress so far

        // Download data in the new thread
        GetRSSDataTask grdt = new GetRSSDataTask();
        grdt.execute("[Feed Address goes here]");

    }

    /**
     * Read RSS channel data.
     * 
     *
     */
    private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssAtomItem> > {
        @Override
        protected List<RssAtomItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                // Create RSS reader
                RssAtomReader rssReader = new RssAtomReader(urls[0]);
                rssReader.setProgressBar(progressBar); // Set the progress bar to show real progress

                // Parse RSS, get items
                return rssReader.getItems();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("BlanketCoffeeRSS", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RssAtomItem> results) {
            // When the download is done the main activity needs to be started
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ListPostsActivity.class);

            // You might find this not right to use a static attribute to pass data between the 
            // the activities in the application. We tried to pass the List of the RssAtomItem 
            // object with no luck although RssAtomItem implemented Serializable interface.
            // ListPostActivity read null values. So this is the engineer's solution. It works :)
            RssResults.setResults(results); //We need to set the results of the download process

            // Show 100% progress
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
            t.setText(done);
            t.show();

            // Start new activity and finish this splash activity
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();

        }

    }

}
```

Can Anybody tell me where am I doing it wrong? The number of author tags are 50, as supposed to the 15 odd posts. Is that creating a problem or something else?

Comment: What happens at at com.itcuties.app.SplashActivity$GetRSSDataTask.onPostExecute(SplashActivity.java:81) ?

Comment: It has a progress bar whose contents are incremented by 1 every time a post is encountered and parsed successfully.

Comment: That's where the exception happens (the logcat mentions it)

Comment: Yeah. But why? I dont know why it happens.

Comment: Could you edit your post with the AsyncTask? (That one mentioned in the logcat)

Comment: I edited my post. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code shows that your toast `t` is null. You create nowhere an instance of it nor call the one-line toast call. E.g. this one:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivty(), R.string.YOUR_STRING, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

You're calling `t.setText(done);` that would cause the null pointer exception, because there is no instance of it.